# Compile a Rust program to an exe using an M1 mac?

Tags: macos, rust

I have written a program in Rust on my M1 Mac, and compiled it to a Unix executable just fine. Now I want to compile it to a Windows executable as well. I first tried

```
$ cargo target add x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
$ cargo build --release --target=x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
```

I got the error message:

> error: linker `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` not found

so I tried

```
$ brew install mingw-w64
```

according to [this](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/cross-compile-macos-and-ms-windows/38323/2), and got the error:

> Error: mingw-w64: no bottle available!

I looked on [formulae.brew.sh](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/mingw-w64) and it seems that `mingw-w64` isn't supported for M1, only Intel.

How can I compile an exe from rust using my M1 Mac?

Answer (score 10):

Solution 1:

You can install/add the targets using these commands :

```
rustup target add x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
rustup toolchain install stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
```

then you can target windows from your mac:

```
cargo build --release --target=x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
```

Solution 2:
Simply use docker!

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
// install rust
COPY project c:/project
RUN cd c:/project && cargo build --release
```

Solution 3:
there is also Cross. you can use this for cross-compilation:
https://github.com/rust-embedded/cross

Comment: I tried solution 1, I still get "error: linker `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` not found"

Comment: If `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` doesn't exist, you may need to install it via `brew install mingw-w64`

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to jump in with a couple newer solutions that worked *really* well for me:

### [`cargo-zigbuild`](https://github.com/messense/cargo-zigbuild)

Targets (`*-pc-windows-gnu` afaik):

- `i686-pc-windows-gnu`
- `x86_64-pc-windows-gnu`

`cargo-zigbuild` also supports cross-compiling to other platforms out of the box as well, with no containerization needed!

Quick example:

```bash
brew install zig
cargo install cargo-zigbuild
cargo zigbuild --target x86_64-pc-windows-gnu -r
```

### [`cargo-xwin`](https://github.com/messense/cargo-xwin)

Targets (`*-msvc` afaik):

- `aarch64-pc-windows-msvc`
- `i586-pc-windows-msvc`
- `i686-pc-windows-msvc`
- `x86_64-pc-windows-msvc`

Quick example:

```bash
cargo install cargo-xwin
cargo xwin build --target x86_64-pc-windows-msvc -r
```

### Which one do I pick?

See: [Difference between the gnu and msvc toolchains?](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/a63dlt/difference_between_the_gnu_and_msvc_toolchains/)

TL;DR: Use `msvc`/`cargo-xwin` for "more native" windows binaries (that are smaller in size) & use `gnu`/`cargo-zigbuild` to help porting over a linux-specific application.

Comment: I was able to do it with in my M1 Mac with `cargo-xwin`, thank you very much for this nice and concise answer.